# Windows Phone 7 - Image Color Overlay from URL

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-7.1

In my Windows Phone 7.1 App, I have a fully functioning `ListBox` which displays data from a web service. In the `ListBox` I was able to put an image and bind the image source to a value returned from the web service using the following `xaml`:

```
<Image Source="{Binding WebImageUrl}" Width="60" Height="60" />
```

This works great. But now I am trying to overlay the image with another color, and to do that I am following the SO question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3950750/how-can-i-change-the-color-of-an-image-in-silverlight-wp7-color-mask). This also works great IF the image explicitly stated. And it does NOT work if I try to bind the url.

For instance, the code:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="60" Height="60">
  <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://someurl.com/repository/images/icon100.png"/>
  </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

works. BUT, the code:

```
<Rectangle Fill="Red" Width="60" Height="60">
  <Rectangle.OpacityMask>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding WebImageUrl}"/>
  </Rectangle.OpacityMask>
</Rectangle>
```

does not. The code compiles file, but Visual Studio throws a parsing error.

**Is there any way to have ImageBrush.ImageSource bind to a string???**

Any thoughts would be much appreciated. I've been at this for a while to no luck.

Cheers,
Brett

Comment: Have you tested listbox with multiple images on the actual phone? Binding url directly is a bad idea with many images. UI freezes to download the data.

Comment: @lukas: I do have it working with the images downloading. I do everything on a background thread, then bind the listbox upon finishing the downloads. The hardcoded URLis just an example which I know works. My question is really about the color overlay. Why does a hardcoded url work but a binding does not?

Answer (score 1):

-- Removed --

Your original code seems to be working fine to me, with a string property, so I don't see any issue...

Comment: This looks simple enough, but I am getting the error: A value of type 'ImageBrush' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'UIElementCollection'. Any ideas?

Comment: Ops, it's not ImageBrush, it's Image... fixing it now!

Comment: Well, it works :-) It's not really what I was going for though. My original code (with the hardcoded uri) only overlays the non-transparent regions of the image with a solid color. This is what I am going for. Your example (although simple) overlays the entire square with an opacity of 0.5. I appreciate you taking the time though!

Comment: Oh, didn't quite get that... let me have another look at the issue!

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something: I just tested it with a property of type string and Uri and it worked on both...